# How to replace Sql Server with Sqlite in Aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to replace sql server with sqlite as database in aspnetboilerplate following [this](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-Core-Sqlite-Integration) tutorial. we have to remove previous migrations and add new one before running "update-database" but it gives empty database and running this project gives error " 'SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AbpEditions". how to populate newly installed sqlite database?

there are SeedHelper.cs and initialHostDbBuilder.cs files in EntityFrameworkCore project, probably for seeding database but i could not figure out how to use them?

Comment: is it aspnetboilerplate or aspnet zero?

Comment: aspnetboilerplate. btw problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that config files in all of your projects that need the access to the database are pointing to the same file. If you have just used the value from the article

```
    "Default": "Data Source=SqliteDemoDb.db"
```

then you have a separate database file in each project. The file that the migrations are executed on is in the EntityFramework project.

Comment: ok. by removing contents of DbContextModelSnapshot.cs first and then adding migrations works fine.